# paladin and anyone else hit same target and causes server crash

Tags: crash, azerothcore

Playing on a linux hosted AzerothCore rev. be423a91b535 master branch.

Whenever as a paladin I hit a target with my abilities and then someone else swings at it the entire server crashes. The only error that shows up in log is this.

We've tested this with multiple characters on multiple accounts and and in all instances after casting either of my judgement of light, or judgement of mana causes the server to crash completely when another character swings at said target.

It does not happen if I do not use these abilities and just attach the target at the same time with another player.

This is a clean server recently set up, no additional modules or changes beyond lowering guild signing size.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWQZc.png)

I've also gotten a snapshot of the server config if that has useful information.

[Server config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFsBG.png)

Comment: please include the error and config as text, so it can be easily found by googling

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there was a module added QAston Proc, and this causes world crashes. If anyone else has this issue updating should clear it up as the commit was removed.